# Converting list of map to a list of objects in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a request to an API which returns me a response.

```
 final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(requestUrl), headers: headers);
```

It returns the following response.

```
{
"meta": {
    "upcomingMatchCount": 5,
    "inProgressMatchCount": 10,
    "completedMatchCount": 5
},
"matchList": {
    "matches": [
        {
            "id": 49944,
            "matchTypeId": 15,
            "series": {
                "id": 2739,
                "name": "LV= Insurance County Championship 2021",
                "shortName": "LV= Insurance County Championship 2021"
            },
            "name": "",
            "status": "LIVE",
            "venue": {
                "name": "The Cooper Associates County Ground",
                "shortName": "The Cooper Associates County Ground"
            },
            "homeTeam": {
                "isBatting": true,
                "id": 55,
                "name": "Somerset",
                "shortName": "SOM"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
                "isBatting": false,
                "id": 46,
                "name": "Gloucestershire",
                "shortName": "GLO"
            },
            "currentMatchState": "Live",
            "isMultiDay": true,
            "matchSummaryText": "Live: Gloucestershire won the toss and elected to bowl.",
            "scores": {
                "homeScore": "8-293",
                "homeOvers": "88.0",
                "awayScore": "0-0",
                "awayOvers": "0"
            },
            "liveStreams": [],
            "isLive": false,
            "currentInningId": 1,
            "isMatchDrawn": false,
            "isMatchAbandoned": false,
            "startDateTime": "2021-04-15T10:00:00Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-04-18T17:00:00Z",
            "isWomensMatch": false,
            "isGamedayEnabled": false,
            "removeMatch": false
        },
        {
            "id": 49942,
            "matchTypeId": 15,
            "series": {
                "id": 2739,
                "name": "LV= Insurance County Championship 2021",
                "shortName": "LV= Insurance County Championship 2021"
            },
            "name": "",
            "status": "LIVE",
            "venue": {
                "name": "The Spitfire Ground, St Lawrence",
                "shortName": "The Spitfire Ground, St Lawrence"
            },
            "homeTeam": {
                "isBatting": false,
                "id": 45,
                "name": "Kent",
                "shortName": "KEN"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
                "isBatting": true,
                "id": 40,
                "name": "Yorkshire",
                "shortName": "YRK"
            },
            "currentMatchState": "Live",
            "isMultiDay": true,
            "matchSummaryText": "Live: Yorkshire won the toss and elected to bat.",
            "scores": {
                "homeScore": "0-0",
                "homeOvers": "0",
                "awayScore": "8-358",
                "awayOvers": "100.0"
            },
            "liveStreams": [],
            "isLive": false,
            "currentInningId": 1,
            "isMatchDrawn": false,
            "isMatchAbandoned": false,
            "startDateTime": "2021-04-15T10:00:00Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-04-18T17:00:00Z",
            "isWomensMatch": false,
            "isGamedayEnabled": false,
            "removeMatch": false
        },
      ]
```

I am retrieving the match list from this response as follows:

```
final list = map['matchList']['matches'] as List;
```

I have a Model class which represents each match from the matches key:

```
class MatchModel {
int id;
int matchTypeId;
Series series;
String name;
String status;
Venue venue;
HomeTeam homeTeam;
HomeTeam awayTeam;
String currentMatchState;
bool isMultiDay;
String matchSummaryText;
Scores scores;
List<Null> liveStreams;
bool isLive;
int currentInningId;
bool isMatchDrawn;
bool isMatchAbandoned;
String startDateTime;
String endDateTime;
bool isWomensMatch;
bool isGamedayEnabled;
bool removeMatch;

MatchModel(
  {this.id,
  this.matchTypeId,
  this.series,
  this.name,
  this.status,
  this.venue,
  this.homeTeam,
  this.awayTeam,
  this.currentMatchState,
  this.isMultiDay,
  this.matchSummaryText,
  this.scores,
  this.liveStreams,
  this.isLive,
  this.currentInningId,
  this.isMatchDrawn,
  this.isMatchAbandoned,
  this.startDateTime,
  this.endDateTime,
  this.isWomensMatch,
  this.isGamedayEnabled,
  this.removeMatch});

MatchModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
id = json['id'];
matchTypeId = json['matchTypeId'];
series =
    json['series'] != null ? new Series.fromJson(json['series']) : null;
name = json['name'];
status = json['status'];
venue = json['venue'] != null ? new Venue.fromJson(json['venue']) : null;
homeTeam = json['homeTeam'] != null
    ? new HomeTeam.fromJson(json['homeTeam'])
    : null;
awayTeam = json['awayTeam'] != null
    ? new HomeTeam.fromJson(json['awayTeam'])
    : null;
currentMatchState = json['currentMatchState'];
isMultiDay = json['isMultiDay'];
matchSummaryText = json['matchSummaryText'];
scores =
    json['scores'] != null ? new Scores.fromJson(json['scores']) : null;
if (json['liveStreams'] != null) {
  liveStreams = new List<Null>();
  json['liveStreams'].forEach((v) {
    
  });
}
isLive = json['isLive'];
currentInningId = json['currentInningId'];
isMatchDrawn = json['isMatchDrawn'];
isMatchAbandoned = json['isMatchAbandoned'];
startDateTime = json['startDateTime'];
endDateTime = json['endDateTime'];
isWomensMatch = json['isWomensMatch'];
isGamedayEnabled = json['isGamedayEnabled'];
removeMatch = json['removeMatch'];
}
```

How do i map data from the list of matches to the list of my MatchModel? Do let me know if you need anything else, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

the thing is the response object which is returned is actually a string, so you need to first convert that to json using like

```
var json = jsonDecode(response). 

Once you have it in json format what you can do is access the list as json['matchList']['matches']. So now you can iterater over it like 

List<MatchModel> matches = []
for(var match in json['matchList']['matches']){
     matches.add(MatchModel.fromJson(match));
}


Hope it's useful.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend JSON serialization with code generation. In that way you just need a annotation `@JsonSerializable` for the class, a constructor and `part 'match.g.dart';` at the begin of your file. After this, the `json_serializable` package will generate the Json-converter-methods/factories for you.

For more information you can use this article: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var json = jsonDecode(response.body)['matchList']['matches'];

List<MatchModel> matches = List.from(json).map((e) => MatchModel.fromJson(Map.from(e))).toList();
```